# What is the difference between $\dfrac{dB}{dt}$ and $\text{rot} B$?

Tags: derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

Yeah, it's rather a physic question but I'm interested especially in algebra meaning. There are Maxwell equations, and one of them, the Faraday's law has  $\dfrac{dB}{dt}$, which 100% means changing magnetic field. As we know changing magnetic field creates by changing electric field, **and hence**, $rotE$ means exactly changing electric field. In Ampere law there is $rotB$, that, by the analogy should means changing magnetic field, but in the right part of equation there is no derivatives by time, so it means that this law about constant fields. But, where then is the logic?

$rot Vector$ or $\nabla \times Vector$ or ($i\dfrac{vector}{dx}+j\dfrac{vector}{dy}+k\dfrac{vector}{dz}$) - there actually are derivatives, and it means something like the degree of the swirl. If it doesn't means "changing" of something, then $rotE$ in Faraday's law should means just a constant current(that can't produce an changing magnetic field)

What do I understand wrong?

Comment: Well fist of all, the Curl (ROT) is a variation, if we want to call it that way, along the spatial components, whilst dB/dt is a time variation.

Comment: @VonNeumann, so space variation doesn't equals time variation?

Comment: Artur: For a simple example consider a static (=time invariant) magnetic field. Then $dB/dt$ is the zero vector, but the curl may still be non-zero.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, hence, rotor B means static?

Comment: Artur: That was just an example of a situation where $dB$ is very clearly different from $\nabla\times B$. Don't read anything else to it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, You mean, $rotor B!=0$ doesn't necessary means $\dfrac{dB }{dt}=0$, or what?